# PHP get next work after a specified paragraph

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a string like this:

```
Staff Juan Dela Cruz < Junior System Developer > total login hours is 12.12 and total adjusted hours is 12. Total worked hours adjustments due to approved worked hours on 2017-05-08. Adjusted Hours is 12 +GST
```

I want to get the `12` after the phrase `Adjusted Hours` . How do I do that? I just always want to get the word after `Adjusted Hours`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
Adjusted Hours is (\d+)
```

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/NdIcwD/1)

Full PHP code:

```
$str = 'Staff Juan Dela Cruz < Junior System Developer > total login hours is 12.12 and total adjusted hours is 12. Total worked hours adjustments due to approved worked hours on 2017-05-08. Adjusted Hours is 12 +GST ';

preg_match('/Adjusted Hours is (\d+)/m', $str, $matches);

var_dump($matches[1]); // => 12
```

[3v41.org demo](https://3v4l.org/eSm8Q)

Comment: @David I have a question though it does not work when the number is decimal? Like 12.43 how do I do that? Thanks!

Comment: @jackhammer013 Change `Adjusted Hours is (\d+)` to `Adjusted Hours is ([\d\.]+)`